# Should I do numerical calculations in-database?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database containing results from many models I've run.  I need to calculate each model's chi^2 value.  I'm using python and the 
 [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)  package to interface with my PostgreSQL database.  I can think of two ways to do this, and I'm not sure which is faster or if there's even a difference.

Method 1:  Select the rows that correspond to each model from my database, then do the chi^2 calculations in python.  Each model has about 500-1000 rows associated with it that I'd have to read in and there are 20,000 models.

Method 2:  Write a SQL function to calculate chi^2 in the database itself, then select this one number for each model.

I'm much more familiar with Python than SQL, so I'm tempted to go with Method 1 on that alone.  However, I can see an advantage to letting postgres optimize the relational algebra and then only having to read in to my python script a single number for each model.  Is there a general strategy I should follow in choosing one method over the other?

Comment: Method 2 looks more efficient.  Plus database functions are re-useable by nature.

Comment: I usually go with Method 2 in this sort of situation

Comment: With only 20,000 records on a proper database server, all filtering and in-row calculations will be virtually instantaneous.

Comment: Postgres supports PL/Python, meaning you could implement method 2 using python as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, chi^2 is not a complex calculation. Whichever method you use is doesn't matter. But I still recommend you use method 2 because the method 1 may lead your application to the OUT OF MEMORY error.